# Send email using boost asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, starttls

**2nd update**: Now the server says: "Ready to start TLS", how to modify my code to perform this TLS negotiation?

I am trying to use boost asio to send an email from one account to another, but failing.

```
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/base64_from_binary.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/transform_width.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/iterators/ostream_iterator.hpp>

using namespace boost::archive::iterators;
typedef base64_from_binary<transform_width<const char *,6,8> > base64_text;

class SMTPClient
{
    public:
        SMTPClient(std::string pServer,unsigned int pPort,std::string pUser,std::string pPassword): mServer(pServer),mPort(pPort),mUserName(pUser),mPassword(pPassword),mSocket(mIOService),mResolver(mIOService)
        {
            tcp::resolver::query qry(mServer,boost::lexical_cast<std::string>( mPort ));
            mResolver.async_resolve(qry,boost::bind(&SMTPClient::handleResolve,this,boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::iterator));
        }

        bool Send(std::string pFrom,std::string pTo,std::string pSubject,std::string pMessage, string &error)
        {
            mFrom=pFrom;
            mTo=pTo;
            mSubject=pSubject;
            mMessage=pMessage;
            mIOService.run();
            error = mErrorMsg;
            return mHasError;
        }

    private:
        std::string encodeBase64(std::string pData)
        {
            std::stringstream os;
            size_t sz=pData.size();
            std::copy(base64_text(pData.c_str()),base64_text(pData.c_str()+sz),std::ostream_iterator<char>(os));
            return os.str();
        }

        void handleResolve(const boost::system::error_code& err,tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
        {
            if(!err)
            {
                tcp::endpoint endpoint=*endpoint_iterator;
                mSocket.async_connect(endpoint,
                boost::bind(&SMTPClient::handleConnect,this,boost::asio::placeholders::error,++endpoint_iterator));
            }
            else
            {
                mHasError=true;
                mErrorMsg= err.message();
            }
        }

        void writeLine(std::string pData)
        {
            std::ostream req_strm(&mRequest);
            req_strm << pData << "\r\n";
            boost::asio::write(mSocket,mRequest);
            req_strm.clear();
        }

        void handleConnect(const boost::system::error_code& err,tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
        {
            if (!err)
            {// The connection was successful. Send the request.
                std::ostream req_strm(&mRequest);
                writeLine("EHLO "+mServer);
                writeLine("STARTTLS");
                writeLine(encodeBase64(mUserName));
                writeLine(encodeBase64(mPassword));
                writeLine( "MAIL FROM:<"+mFrom+">");
                writeLine( "RCPT TO:<"+mTo+">");
                writeLine( "DATA");
                writeLine( "SUBJECT:"+mSubject);
                writeLine( "From:"+mFrom);
                writeLine( "To:"+mTo);
                writeLine( "");
                writeLine( mMessage );
                writeLine( ".\r\n");
            }
            else
            {
                mHasError=true;
                mErrorMsg= err.message();
            }

        size_t s = -1;
        while(s > 0 || s == -1)
        {
            const int max_length = 4096;
            char data[max_length];
            boost::system::error_code error;
            s = mSocket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data), error);

            if(s > 0)
            {
                char d[4096];
                strncpy(d, data, s);
                d[s] = '\0';
                cout << d;
            }
        }
        }

        std::string mServer;
        std::string mUserName;
        std::string mPassword;
        std::string mFrom;
        std::string mTo;
        std::string mSubject;
        std::string mMessage;
        unsigned int mPort;
        boost::asio::io_service mIOService;
        tcp::resolver mResolver;
        tcp::socket mSocket;
        boost::asio::streambuf mRequest;
        boost::asio::streambuf mResponse;
        bool mHasError;
        std::string mErrorMsg;
};

bool send_mail(string text, string &error)
{
    string 
        subject = "Subject",
        me_mail = "xxx@gmail.com",
        me_mail_server = "smtp.gmail.com",
        me_user = "xxx@gmail.com",
        me_pass = "xxx_pass",
        target_mail = "yyy@gmail.com";

    int server_port = 587;

    SMTPClient mailc(me_mail_server, server_port, me_user, me_pass);
    return mailc.Send(me_mail, target_mail, subject, text, error);
}
```

Can you please help me? I am not experienced about the smtp protocol, so I found this difficult...

Comment: If you don't log what the mail server replied, you'll never know why the stuff is failing.

Comment: I am doing this by viewing the err.message() on handleConnect function and says: "The operation completed successfully"

Comment: You need to log what the mail server is replying to your commands. (You're in fact, I believe, supposed to wait until the server has replied to some of them before proceeding with the others.) The `err` object is irrelevant for this.

Comment: I managed to get a reply, but I am not sure to post it because it may contain my password... it says: "220 mx.google.com ESMTP xxxxxxxxxxxxx - gsmtp"

Comment: Please stop posting comments like that. [Edit] your question and add all the details. That reply you got is just the first one, you should get one reply per command you send, and you need to analyze them. See the SMTP protocol docs.