# Sending gmail using port 587

Tags: email

I am trying to send a gmail, here are the commands, using port 587:

```
EHLO smtp.gmail.com
STARTTLS
AUTH LOGIN
base64_encoded_username
base64_encoded_password
MAIL FROM:<me@gmail.com>
RCPT TO:<other@gmail.com>
DATA
SUBJECT: Hello!
This is the text
QUIT
```

The server says "Ready to start TLS" What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well, are you actually doing the TLS negotiation?

Comment: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3207.txt  Basically, at the STARTTLS point, you negotiate TLS (using OpenSSL or similar) and then basically start all over again.  Might be easier to use a library to help with the SSL/TLS parts of this, e.g. http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-tls.html

Comment: I am trying many hours and I have read that page but I simply don't understand what I am doing wrong... If you have any idea, I will really appreciate it. I am trying to do this in boost::asio.

Comment: What library are you using for SSL/TLS?

Comment: I am not using any library for tls/ssl. Here is my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594962

Comment: If you want to do TLS, you **need** to use a library. Please look at what TLS is in Wikipedia, it's not something you'll be able to implement yourself in a 20-line program.

Comment: I just want to send a gmail... So, I need boost::asio and a tls library. Do you have any suggestion, is there a boost implementation? Why so hard, in php you can do it in 5 lines...